# Configurar log de erros

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou trabalhando com PHP e estou na parte de sustentação, mas não conheço bem o sistema de erros. Existe algum material que eu possa ler para me auxiliar?

O meu maior problema é o seguinte, muitos erros são escritos no log desta maneira:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'vc-icon-element.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\js_composer\config\conte on line 6
```

Mas parece que o caminho não está completo e não sei qual arquivo fez a requisição do `vc-icon-element.php`. Como eu faria para descobrir qual arquivo ou pagina que gerou esse log? É normal o caminho não chegar até um arquivo `.php`?

Comment: E essa parte: `in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\js_composer\config\conte on line 6`? No caso, é este caminho que está incompleto?

Comment: exatamente isso, ele não deveria ir até um arquivo.php??

Comment: Acredito que sim. Esse caminho possui algum caractere especial?

Comment: Nenhum caractere especial

Comment: E eu não sei se é falha minha por não saber identificar o erro, ou se tem alguma coisa errada com as configurações do error_log

Comment: Se vc tiver o projeto na sua maquina, vc pode fazer uma busca em todo lugar que faz referencia ao `vc-icon-element.php`. Mas sim, era pro log aparecer completo

Comment: Mas não tem uma maneira de fazer com que os logs sejam escritos com o caminho completo ? Pq esse foi um dos exemplos de erros que ocorrem, existem outros que não dão nem o nome do arquivo que está sendo pedido

Comment: @KaueAlves vc tá lendo esse log como? no terminal? num editor de texto?

Comment: Em um editor de texto, sublime.

Comment: Nao ta faltando uma \ entre www e root? Ao ives de `wwwroot` nao seria `www\root`?

Comment: Não, é o nome da pasta mesmo.

Comment: Resolvido -  
I'm guessing the line is getting truncated - it shouldn't, but maybe there is a setting in php.ini shoretning the default (the default should be 1024 bytes - ie, 1kB) - look here php.net/manual/en/… – junkfoodjunkie

php.ini estava errado.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que está tendo um limite de caracteres ai, e por isso não exibe o caminho completo do diretório por ser um caminho muito longo.

Sei q existe uma configuração de limite de caracteres para os erros que são exibidos na tela, só não sei se serve também para os registros de log.

Mas tenta dar uma olhada na documentação do php e tentar mudar a configuração de limite de caracteres no php.ini pra ver se resolve.

Segue o link: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len